# Can't make migrations run after upgrading to Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-migrations

I'm trying to upgrade my Django 1.6.2 application to Django 1.7.10 but am stuck because the makemigrations command keeps raising an error.  I've never used migrations in this application.  When I run the command "python ./manage.py makemigrations", I get the following error:

```
... # stacktrace
File "/Users/myname/venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 248, in __init__
  raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model))
  ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field my.admin.PhotoQueue.review_queue: my.admin.my.admin.ReviewQueue
```

where my.admin is the AppConfig label for the "admin" app whose models module contains the classes in question:

```
# apps/admin/models.py   <- I keep all my apps in an "apps" subdirectory in my project
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class ReviewQueue(models.Model):
    """Queue contains changes that need to be reviewed."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...  # more declarations

class PhotoQueue(models.Model):
    """Queue contains information about photos uploaded by a user."""
    review_queue = models.OneToOneField(ReviewQueue, primary_key=True)
```

As you can see, an item in my review queue can optionally be related to an item in my photo queue.  The ReviewQueue and PhotoQueue classes reside in the same module and the ReviewQueue is declared right before the PhotoQueue.  I've looked online to see if anyone else has had this problem but didn't see anything.  I've also looked to see if there are any issues relating to migrations and OneToOneFields, again with no luck.  Does anyone know what is causing this problem? My business is dead if I can't resolve it.

Here are my installed apps and appconfig:

```
# conf/settings/base.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # Project apps
    'apps.admin',
    'apps.members',
)

# apps/admin/models/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.admin'
    label = 'my.admin'
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to see your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and your app config.

Comment: I've added them.  Thanks.

Comment: Try a label without a dot, e.g. `myadmin` instead of `my.admin`.

Comment: That seemed to fix the error!  How did you know that?  I now have another problem but at least I'm past this one.  Thanks very much.

Comment: It's easy to miss, but the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) say the label 'should be a valid Python identifier', so I thought the problem might be the dot.

Comment: Well, thanks again.  I never would have caught that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) in your app config should not have a dot in it. You could do:

```
class AdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.admin'
    label = 'myadmin'
```